# Magento visitor data is not getting populated, why?

Tags: magento-enterprise, session, php-5.4

I need Magento's visitor_id to save some data against visitors come to my Magento store. 
But I found in some instances `$session[visitor_data]` array is empty. But I can see frontend cookie is created.

1. Have anyone came across this situation?
2. How do I populate visitor id, if its not available?
3. If this is not possible what would be the best way to uniquely identify a visitor?

Answer (score 6):

Look at /app/code/core/Mage/Log/Model/Visitor.php You can use the same event to get the data you want (Ref: /app/code/core/Mage/Log/etc/config.xml)

```
public function saveByRequest($observer)
{
    if ($this->_skipRequestLogging || $this->isModuleIgnored($observer)) {
        return $this;
    }

    try {
        $this->setLastVisitAt(now());
        $this->save();
        $this->_getSession()->setVisitorData($this->getData());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::logException($e);
    }
    return $this;
}
```